# How to filter a MOSS2007 Content Query Web Part using a custom column?

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, sharepoint-2007, cqwp

I am trying to setup a content query web part in MOSS that will display documents on a page based on a choice column that I created.  I have created a "Page" column and added it as a core document column for my site.  What I would like the CQWP to do is filter the document list that is displayed based on this Page column.  However, this column does not show up as a filter in the CQWP on the page.  I tried following the instructions in this question: [Content Query WebPart - Grouping by custom column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848695/content-query-webpart-grouping-by-custom-column) to no avail.  Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [CommonViewFields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.contentbyquerywebpart.commonviewfields.aspx) as [suggested](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms497457.aspx) in the second answer from that [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848695/content-query-webpart-grouping-by-custom-column)? You can edit the property in SharePoint Designer or by exporting the web part, changing the CommonViewFields in Notepad, and then re-importing the web part. If CommonViewFields doesn't work, you can always modify the filter property directly in either SPD or using export-Notepad-import. Be sure you are pointing to a Content Type that includes your custom field.

Comment: How do you access the filter directly (sorry, I'm a little new with SPD)?

Comment: In SPD, select the CQWP. In the CategoryConfigureQuery category of the Tag Properties pane, edit FilterField1, FilterOperator1, FilterType1, and FilterValue1. Instead of starting with a blank slate, I would set the filter to a field that is appearing in the webpart builder in the browser and then modify the settings as necessary in SPD.